# Django Admin Inline Change List

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I can edit a parent child relationship using the TablularInline and StackedInline classes, however I would prefer to list the child relationships as a change list as there is a lot of information and the forms are too big.  Is there an inline change list available in DJango admin or a way or creating one?

Comment: The "change list" in the Django admin is the list of instances for a given model. The implication here is that he wants his inline to display a simple list of instances (with link to the individual edit form for each), not a list of inline forms.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such functionality built in, but I don't think it would be hard to create your own AdminInline subclass (and an accompanying template for it) that would do this. Just model it off TabularInline, but display fields' data directly instead of rendering form fields.

Answer (score 0):

So I was actually able to achieve this with quite the hack. Django Admin needs some updates and InlineAnything would be one.

Download Library: https://github.com/smartlgt/django-fakeinline

```
class MyInlineTest(FakeInline):
  def __init__(self, parent_model, admin_site):
    super().__init__(parent_model, admin_site)
    self.template = Template('')
    self.admin_site = admin_site
    
  def get_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    dpaa = DisplayProductAccessAdmin(DisplayProductAccess, self.admin_site)
    dpaa.change_list_template = 'test.html'
    self.template = Template(dpaa.changelist_view(request, {}).rendered_content)
    return FakeInline.get_fields(self, request, obj=obj)
```

Then in your test.html, take most of the contents of the change_list.html from Django. Since we're using Jazzmin let's go with that.

```
    {% load i18n admin_urls static admin_list jazzmin %}

{% block extrastyle %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'vendor/select2/css/select2.min.css' %}">

    {% if cl.formset or action_form %}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>
    {% endif %}
    {{ media.css }}
    {% if not actions_on_top and not actions_on_bottom %}
        <style>
            #changelist table thead th:first-child {width: inherit}
        </style>
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}

{% block extrahead %}
    {{ media.js }}
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="col-12">
        <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h4 class="card-title">{{ title }}{% block pretitle %}{% endblock %}</h4>
                <div class="card-tools form-inline">
                    {% block date_hierarchy %}{% if cl.date_hierarchy %}{% date_hierarchy cl %}{% endif %}{% endblock %}
                    {% block search %}
                        {% search_form cl %}
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card-body">
                <form id="changelist-form" method="post"{% if cl.formset and cl.formset.is_multipart %}enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %} novalidate>{% csrf_token %}
                    <div id="content-main">
                        {% if cl.formset and cl.formset.errors %}
                        <p class="errornote">
                            {% if cl.formset.total_error_count == 1 %}
                                {% trans "Please correct the error below." %}
                            {% else %}
                                {% trans "Please correct the errors below." %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </p>
                        {{ cl.formset.non_form_errors }}
                        {% endif %}
                        <div class="module{% if cl.has_filters %} filtered{% endif %}" id="changelist">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-12">
                                {% if cl.formset %}
                                    <div>{{ cl.formset.management_form }}</div>
                                {% endif %}

                                {% block result_list %}
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
                                            {% if action_form and actions_on_top and cl.show_admin_actions %}
                                                {% admin_actions %}
                                            {% endif %}
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
                                            {% block object-tools %}
                                                {% block object-tools-items %}
                                                    {% change_list_object_tools %}
                                                {% endblock %}
                                            {% endblock %}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <hr/>
                                    {% result_list cl %}
                                    {% if action_form and actions_on_bottom and cl.show_admin_actions %}
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-12">
                                                {% admin_actions %}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endblock %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            {% block pagination %}{% pagination cl %}{% endblock %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

        </div>
        <br class="clear"/>
    </div>
{% endblock %}

{% block extrajs %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'vendor/select2/js/select2.min.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'jazzmin/js/change_list.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

[image]